# Debugging OOM error observed

Tags: java, kernel, jna

Kernel kills my java server with

```
java invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x24201ca, order=0, oom_score_adj=0
```

Java server uses to JNA to invoke C/C++ library. I was able to see that JVM heap size was not increasing but system free memory kept on decreasing.

Java server has 4 GB JVM running on 16 GB host. Heap uses is always between 35-50% after GC. Is there a way to understand why free memory is decreasing even though heap size is not increasing. Restarting the java server brings free size to normal value.

I am not able to understand how extra memory is associated with java process but heap size is not increasing.

Comment: What is the native library doing? It could be that you have some drastic memory leaks going on, perhaps you're forgetting to close/release handles.